# json value in multiChoiceItem

Tags: android, dialog, multichoiceitems

I have json array I want to show  just value in a a dailog. Ho can I achieve this? This is the code i wrote

```
public JsonArray arrayListToJson(List<String> selectedItems) {
    JsonObject jsonObject ;
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for (String selectedItem : selectedItems) {
        jsonObject= new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty(selectedItem, selectedItem);
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);

    }
    return jsonArray;
}
public ArrayList<String> getJsonValues(JsonArray jsonArray){
    ArrayList<String> selectedValues= new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<JsonElement> iterator =jsonArray.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        selectedValues.add(iterator.next().toString());
    }
    return selectedValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with following code snipet.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        for (String currentItem : selectedItems) {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put(currentItem, "test");
                Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String keys = iterator.next().toString();
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject.get(keys));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
```